# First App - crashing on startActivity

Tags: android

I am very new to Android and have a simple piece of code which has some buttons and when one is clicked it opens the next screen correct (PriceScreen) but when the other is clicked the (LocationScreen) crashes on the line startActivity(viewlocationScreen);

The code for both LocationScreen.java and PriceScreen.java "seems" to be quite identicle.
The code calling it is

```
public class TaxiAppActivity extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);   

        Button bBtnYes = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnYes);
        bBtnYes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(View arg0) {
           Intent viewLocationScreen = new  Intent(TaxiAppActivity.this,LocationScreen.class);
//           Intent viewLocationScreen = new Intent(TaxiAppActivity.this,PriceScreen.class);
               startActivity(viewLocationScreen); // << error here

           }  
        });

        Button cBtnGetPrice = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGetPrices);
        cBtnGetPrice.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(View arg0) {
           Intent viewPriceScreen = new Intent(TaxiAppActivity.this,PriceScreen.class);
           startActivity(viewPriceScreen);
           }  
        });

//      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
```

In the above code if I comment out the line

```
Intent viewLocationScreen = new Intent(TaxiAppActivity.this,LocationScreen.class);
```

and use .... PriceScreen.class); as the end instead .. it works.
Can anyone tell me why?

Thanks in advance
Tony

Comment: Did you add the `LocationScreen` activity to your manifest?

Comment: "Can anyone tell me why?" - Just a guess but you haven't declared `LocationScreen` as an `<activity>` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`? If that's not the answer then post the logcat output.

Comment: Welcome to SO. When trying to solve a crash in Java / Android, it is better to add the stack trace with the exception details, this way no one will need to guess too much and it will be easier to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you register the 2nd activity in the manifest file?
If you could post your manifest file too it would be helpful in diagnosing the issue.

All activities used in the application must have an entry in the manifest file in order for android to actually launch them.

Additional Activities that don't need to show up in the launcher can be registered in the manifest file like this (from the application I'm currently working on)

```
<activity
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name=".LineupActivity">
</activity>
```

With ".LineupActivity" in the example replaced with whatever the class name of your activity is.  In your case `.LocationScreen`.

Comment: There is a definition in the Android manifest.xml for this activity.
Here is most of the file
...
...
        <activity android:name=".LocationScreen" android:label="Location Screen" >
        </activity> 
        <activity android:name=".PriceScreen" android:label="Price Screen" >
        </activity> 
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    </application>
</manifest>

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the stacktrace and exception details from the logcat output?

Comment: I am relatively new to android.. and see in the console that there seems to be a permissions problem writing to the file.